# Progressbar in listboxitem

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

i got a listbox with items and i use datatemplate to display the items

i want to make a download button, once the user select an item and click the button a progress bar will be added to the selected item datatemplate and will display the download progress, is it possible ?

any pointers will help

```
 <ListBox Name="List" Grid.Row="2" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListTemplate}" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RoundedItem}" 
                 BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" 
                 Background="{x:Null}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can create and `<ItemTemplate>` that contains both the "normal" representation of the item as well as the progress bar. Initially you set the `Visibility` of the progress bar to `Collapsed`. When the download starts you change the `Visibility` to `Visible` (you may also want to collapse other parts of the item).

You can databind the `Visibility` property to a property of the view-model of the item. You could use a boolean property like `IsDownloading` and then bind through a converter that converts `true` to `Visible` and `false` to `Collapsed`.

To show the progress bar you simply set `IsDownloading` to true and fire the `PropertyChanged` event. When download is complete you set `IsDownloading` to false and fire the `PropertyChanged` event again.

Here is a rough sketch on how you can do it. You need a view-model class for your item in the `ListView` that you can databind to:

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  public String Name { ... }

  public Double Progress { ... }

  public Boolean IsDownloading { ... }

  ...

}
```

You also need an `IValueConverter` that can convert `Boolean` to `Visibility`:

```
class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {

  public Boolean Invert { get; set; }

  Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    var visible = Convert.ToBoolean(value) ^ Invert;
    return visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

  Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw NotImplementedException();
  }

}
```

Your view should be based on something like this:

```
<ListBox
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="InverseVisibilityConverter" Invert="True"/>
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <TextBlock
          Text="{Binding Name}"
          Visibility="{Binding IsDownloading, Converter={StaticResource InverseVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <ProgressBar
          Value="{Binding Progress}"
          Visibility="{Binding IsDownloading, Converter={StaticResource VisbilityConverter}}"/>
      </Grid>
    <DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: nice, but how can i bind to the progress bar and update it from the vm ?

Comment: @ibm123 Martin showed it in his example the Item class has the property Progress which is bound to the progressbar. This is what you want. But you might want to do the actual downloading in a BackgroundWorker and use the ReportProgress method. Also it might be useful to implement a thread safe version of INotifyPropertyChanged which can be acomplished with the Dispatcher, Invoke/BeginInvoke and CheckAccess methods of the dispatcher.